# Help Unlocking a Wallet

Tags: jaxx

So, I participated in an ICO a while back, and to send the ETH over to the ICO Contract address, I used Jaxx (stupid me).

When I told Jaxx to send the funds over, Jaxx actually and inexplicably created a secondary address in the wallet, and then promptly deleted the private key. I've never seen this behavior from a wallet before, and it's stumped the idiots over at the Jaxx support team, because all I did was hit "send."

So, my ICO Tokens are now stuck in a secondary address that I don't have the private key for, but I'm wondering if there's any way I can unlock it using the mnemonic Jaxx used in the first place, for the original wallet. I have to assume they were derived from the same mnemonic, after all.

Before it's suggested, I've tried importing the mnemonic into MEW, but it doesn't have any way for me to sort through the millions of addresses the mnemonic creates. The address is not in the first hundred-odd pages, and the website crashes after a while, if you keep digging down through the addresses. I really need a way to sort to a specific address.

So really, my question is, is there a way I can open a **specific** address with a Jaxx mnemonic?

Thanks for any and all suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering the mnemonic here: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/, and set the "coin" to "ETH - Ethereum". Then flip through the "derived addresses."

I downloaded the Jaxx Chrome extension and generated a wallet. For me, the first derived address from iancoleman.io/bip39 for that mnemonic matched the address that Jaxx gave me. Hopefully, one of the addresses will match for you.

I didn't try the same experiment with MEW, but I do know that wallets vary in the derivation paths they use, so it's good to use a tool that you know matches Jaxx.

It would be surprising if you really had to go through "millions of addresses," since presumably you haven't created that many, and when Jaxx generated a new one, it should have been nearby the ones you were already using.

Good luck recovering the ether! I hope this helps.

Comment: Just for anyone else reading the above answer... By entering your mnemonic into a web page, you could be effectively giving away your private key. Yes, I've personally used the site in the past, but at any point it could be subverted/hacked/etc. If you're unsure how much you should trust Ian Coleman and random URLs, there's an offline version of the same tool, here: https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39

Comment: Yes, thank you for that word of warning! Be especially suspicious of someone on the internet telling you a URL where you should reveal your private key. :-) The offline version is a  much safer way to go.

Comment: I did try the iancoleman tool, but it didn't have my address listed... which means... jaxx didn't use the same mnemonic to create the address.

Wow.

Is it possible that this is some kind of screwed up HD-wallet function? 

It might be helpful if I point to the actual transactions. 

I currently have access to the 0x33fe wallet. That's the original wallet. When I went to send ETH, Jaxx created 0xe866, and then sent them to the contract address at 0xBEc5.

So, just for clarity, I need to unlock 0xe866.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x33fef8fd5c32c648c802ee080c29568e549162ff

Comment: I'm out of ideas... I hope the Jaxx support team is able to figure out what happened and provide some assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The iancoleman tool was a great idea.